# React: Reorder children components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have wrapper component which in some cases I need to reorder the position of only one of the children on it, sometimes I require to have ComponentX at the top, sometimes at the bottom. Is there any elegant way to achieve this? because I did it but replicating code.

```
const ComponentX = () => <h4>component x</h4>
const Component1 = () => <h4>component 1</h4>
const Component2 = () => <h4>component 2</h4>

const ComponentWrapper = ({xOnTop = false}) => {
  return (
    <div className="box">
       <h1>My components</h1>
        {xOnTop && <ComponentX />}
        <Component1 />
        <Component2 />
        {!xOnTop && <ComponentX />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/napstercake/pen/RwLerBj)

Comment: What's wrong with the current implementation? It seems fit-for-purpose.

Comment: I don't know, @evolutionxbox I saw it kind of duplicated, you're probably right about fitting the purpose. Thanks!

Comment: That works. Another alternative would be to push the components into an array in the order you want and use function `map` to return each component from the array. In more complex cases with lots of data entries I use a "at" value and when the data is pulled from the database I order it by "at", where "at" is an integer from 0 to n - 1.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is perfectly fine, but I tried to come up with a different way to go about it and came up with this. So you can easily just invert the order of the component's keys using the xOnTop parameter.

```
const components = [
  <h4 key="1">component x</h4>,
  <h4 key="2">component 1</h4>,
  <h4 key="2">component 2</h4>
 ]

const ComponentWrapper = ({xOnTop = true}) => {
  components.sort((a, b) => xOnTop ? a.key - b.key : b.key - a.key)
  return (
    <div className="box">
      <h1>My components</h1>
      {components.map(c => c)}
    </div>
  )
}
```